# Extract PNGs embedded in a file

Tags: image, rust, file-structure

My approach was to find each occurrence of the PNG's file signature followed by its end of file (EOF) and write the bytes between to a new file whose name is simply a counter starting at zero.

```
use std::env;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;

const SIGNATURE: [u8; 8] = [137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10];
const EOF: [u8; 8] = [73, 69, 78, 68, 174, 66, 96, 130];

fn main() {
    let path = env::args().nth(1).unwrap();
    let mut f = File::open(path).unwrap();

    let mut buf = Vec::new();
    f.read_to_end(&mut buf).unwrap();

    let mut iter = buf.iter();
    let mut i = 0;

    while let Some(start) = iter.rposition(|&x| x == SIGNATURE[0]) {

        if buf[start..].starts_with(&SIGNATURE) {

            let mut iter = buf[start..].iter();

            let mut end = iter.position(|&x| x == 130).unwrap();

            loop {
                let slice = &buf[start..start + end + 1];
                if slice.ends_with(&EOF) {
                    let mut f = File::create(i.to_string() + ".png").unwrap();
                    f.write_all(slice).unwrap();
                    i += 1;
                    break;
                }

                end += match iter.position(|&x| x == 130) {
                    Some(x) => { x + 1 },
                    None => break,
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only reason I used `rposition` instead of `position` for `start` was because the file I was working with had all its PNG's embedded at the end.

I had attempted to replace some of the `unwrap`s with `try!`s but realized that the macro needs to be called from a function that returns a `Result`, i.e. can't be used in `fn main()`, and couldn't figure out how best to break up the code.

Was wondering if there might be a better way to approach the problem. If not, how can I at least clean up this implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use `expect` instead of `unwrap`. This gives you and your users
   a better chance at figuring out what went wrong. It's also one step closer
   to good error reporting and handling.
2. Extract an `inner_main` that returns a `Result` and thus allows
   you to use `try!`. `main` can call that method, pattern match on the
   `Result`, print the failure message, have an exit code, etc.
3. To start with, return a `Result<_, Box<Error>>`. `Box<Error>` is an easy
   type to build, and `try!` can convert to it automatically.
4. Once you are returning `Results, the`expect`s can be transformed into a`
   Result`using`Option::ok_or`.
5. One Rust-specific way to think about splitting up functions is
   to constrain mutability. Extracting out loading the file allows the
   `Vec` to be mutable in the smallest possible scope.
6. It may be over engineering, but creating an iterator to handle
   finding the embedded PNGs helps separate concerns. For example, I
   didn't originally see that `i` wasn't part of the main finding
   logic. It would also allow you to create more focused unit tests on
   just this complicated functionality.
7. The search algorithm itself isn't super efficient; it doesn't
   skip as much data as it could in certain places, it seems to always
   scan through to the end of the file. What if your data was
   something like `SIG ... SIG ... SIG ... EOF`?
8. The magic number `130` for the end position is duplicated.
9. Use a crate like [twoway](https://crates.io/crates/twoway) to do
   the heavy lifting of searching for byte substrings. This takes care of a
   lot of the annoying details.
10. The data is sliced for the same range multiple times. Any array access is a tiny bit expensive as it has to do range checks. Doing it once is good for both programmer sanity and for the tiny gain in speed.
11. Using `format!` to construct the file name may be more obvious than adding a string slice to a `String`.

---

```
extern crate twoway;

use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::path::Path;
use std::{env, process};

const SIGNATURE: [u8; 8] = [137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10];
const EOF: [u8; 8] = [73, 69, 78, 68, 174, 66, 96, 130];

fn load_file<P>(path: P) -> Result<Vec<u8>, Box<Error>>
    where P: AsRef<Path>
{
    let mut f = try!(File::open(path));

    let mut buf = Vec::new();
    try!(f.read_to_end(&mut buf));
    Ok(buf)
}

struct EmbeddedPng<'a>(&'a [u8]);

impl<'a> Iterator for EmbeddedPng<'a> {
    type Item = &'a [u8];

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        loop {
            match twoway::rfind_bytes(self.0, &SIGNATURE) {
                None => return None,
                Some(start_idx) => {
                    let (before, after) = self.0.split_at(start_idx);
                    self.0 = before;

                    if let Some(end_idx) = twoway::find_bytes(after, &EOF) {
                        let png_data = &after[..end_idx + EOF.len()];
                        return Some(png_data)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fn inner_main() -> Result<(), Box<Error>> {
    let path = try!(env::args().nth(1).ok_or("No filename provided"));
    let buf = try!(load_file(path));

    for (i, png_data) in EmbeddedPng(&buf).enumerate() {
        let fname = format!("{}.png", i);
        let mut f = try!(File::create(fname));
        try!(f.write_all(png_data));
    }

    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    if let Err(e) = inner_main() {
        println!("{}", e);
        process::exit(1);
    }
}
```